# ajax is not responding anything

Tags: php, ajax

I am creating a web page which allows user to give rating to a product.I am using ajax to send data to a php server which should, in my case, return `{"error":"reviewalready"}`. But ajax is not responding, I don't know why ?. I ran server page manually, and it is fine. I tried all the answers to the same problem but nothing helped me.
Here is `index.php` which contain form

```
<!-- Review and rating form -->
            <div class="review-form">
                <p id="feedbackMessage" style="color:red;"></p>
                <form id="feedbackForm" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" id="hiddenpid" name="pid" class="form-control" value = "<?=$pid?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="review" name="feedMessage" cols="50" rows="3" placeholder="Your feedback"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  value="Post" id="feedBtn">
                </form>
          </div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#feedbackForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    formData.append("ratedindex", ratedindex + 1);
    console.log("Form submitted");
    $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: "viewserver.php",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            /* res = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(res.error); */
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Server page `viewserver.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbconnection.php';
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');

$userrating = $_POST['ratedindex'];
$userfeedback = $_POST['feedMessage'];
$pid = $_POST['pid'];
$date = date("DD M,y h:i a");
if (isset($_SESSION['uid']) || isset($_COOKIE['uid'])) {
  if (isset($_COOKIE['uid'])) $uid = $_COOKIE['uid'];
  else $uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
  $sql = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM `product_rating` WHERE `user_id` = ? AND `product_id` = ?");
  $sql->bind_param("ii", $uid, $pid);
  $sql->execute();
  $result = $sql->get_result();
  if (($result -> num_rows) > 0) {
     echo json_encode(array("error" => "reviewalready"));
  } else {
     $sql = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `product_rating` (`user_id`, `product_id`, `rating`, `review`, `date`) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
     $sql->bind_param("iiiss", $uid, $pid, $userrating, $userfeedback, $date);
     if ($sql->execute()) {
         echo json_encode(array("success" => "posted"));
     } else {
        echo json_encode(array("error" => "postfailed"));
     }
   }
  } else {
     echo json_encode(array("error" => "login"));
  }

?>
```

Form is being submitted but ajax is not working. I find everything correct, but I don't know why this problem is wasting my time ?

Comment: Your Ajax call specifies that it should be sent as "method=POST", but your PHP code is looking for `$_GET` variables.

Comment: oops, i forgot to update that, I did that when I was running server manually. That is no the problem.

Comment: Why do you have contentType and processData set to false? Doesn't the first need to be set as the default for PHP to be able to extract the form variables? And isn't it `$sql->num_rows` rather than `$result->num_rows`? I don't use mysqli myself so I'm not sure, but doc suggests it is.

Comment: I didn't get you. I did that because I am sending data as JSON format. `$result -> num_rows` is correct.

Comment: What happens if you remove those two lines? What is in `$_POST` when you `var_dump` it?

Comment: I will throw an error `Uncaught error : illegal invocation` [link](https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/jquery/8941-getting-started-with-jquery-advanced-ajax.html?start=1#:~:text=processData,encoding%20as%20a%20query%20string.)

Comment: How I can check check using `var_dump()` ?

Comment: var_dump() the array, exit the PHP, and your JS should log it to the console.

Comment: No response from the server is shown

Comment: There would be problem in my index page where the form is, because I tried ajax with another button to do something and that didn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by modifying the Javascript code. I removed `contentTpe : false` and `processData : false` and instead of sending form data I created an object `_data`.

```
$("#feedBtn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var feedMessage = $("#review").val();
    var pid = parseInt($("#hiddenpid").val());
    var _data = {
        'ratedindex': ratedindex + 1,
        'feedMessage': feedMessage,
        'pid': pid
    };
    console.log(_data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "viewserver.php",
        data: _data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
    });
});
```

And it is working.